# Ultimate solution to defer javascript and jquery after page is loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, pagespeed

As you probably know, [Google PageSpeed Insights](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights) wants you to defer your javascript.

Google itself [suggests a solution](https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/best-practices/payload?hl=it#DeferLoadingJS) to defer your code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function downloadJSAtOnload()
    {
        var element = document.createElement("script");
        element.src = "deferredfunctions.js";
        document.body.appendChild(element);
    }
    if (window.addEventListener) window.addEventListener("load", downloadJSAtOnload, false);
    else if (window.attachEvent) window.attachEvent("onload", downloadJSAtOnload);
    else window.onload = downloadJSAtOnload;
</script>
```

Of course is a good solution, but it's far from the real circumstances (many scripts to include, code to execute, etc...)

Strating from an example:

```
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script type='text/javascript' src='...'></script>
        <script type='text/javascript' src='...'></script>
        <script type='text/javascript' src='...'></script>
        <script type='text/javascript'><!--
            // some code
            $(document).ready(function(){
                // code to execute when the page is ready
            });
        --></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

The question is: How to apply the Google suggestion to the example above?

Comment: given that your second sample requires that jquery be loaded to execute, you wouldn't gain much. "load some JS so you can defer loading JS".

Comment: You are right Marc, but Google PageSpeed doesn't say the same. It continues to show me the advice: "defer JavaScript execution until page load". Do you think I can omit this?

Answer (score -1):

The Google example can work for multiple scripts if you have the `downloadJSatOnload` append several script elements to the page, and then call the code you would normally put in `$(document).ready(function () { ... });`. That code could be called explicitly or be the last file downloaded.

Comment: I've tried to apply this solution. All the jquery scripts work (slideshow, map, form validation) but I got the "Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined" error. It's like the ready block is executed before all the scripts, but everything works the same. How is it possible?

Comment: Can you edit the question to include the code you tried?  Also, see some of the linked questions, they're very similar to this one and might provide some ideas.

Comment: Edited. I've considered the solution showed [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5853358/162049) but it can be applyed to just one script and it doesn't fit my needs - maybe I'm missing some uses of that code?

Comment: I've edited again, in order to keep the questions clear and separated. I've continue the argument in [this another question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15949219/why-this-code-doesnt-work)