# How to detect if jquery has finished loading using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
  function downloadJSAtOnload() {
 var element = document.createElement("script");
 element.src = "//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js";
 document.body.appendChild(element);
 }

 if (window.addEventListener)
 window.addEventListener("load", downloadJSAtOnload, false);
 else if (window.attachEvent)
 window.attachEvent("onload", downloadJSAtOnload);
 else window.onload = downloadJSAtOnload;
```

Ok so I'm using [**googles tip**](https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/insights/BlockingJS) to defer loading of jQuery and fix any `Render-blocking` issue.

The issue happens when you are `blocking external script during parsing` which is loading `jQuery` or any other `large javascript files` that is not needed to render the above-the-fold region. So with the code above the issue is fixed. BUT I have one problem I have codes that run `$(document).ready()` but it bugs up because jQuery hasn't loaded yet.

How do I find out if jQuery has finished loading?

Comment: Are you able to inline the `jQuery` load within the `HTML` itself?

Comment: Well, if your other functions are reliant on `$(document).ready()`, just put the `jQuery` load in the `head` of your `HTML`, rather than injecting it with a `script`.

Comment: we need to defer jQuery because it will cause render-blocking so No we should not just load it on the head tag like we used to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option would be to put the script tag at the end of the body, or:

```
(function() {
  function getScript(url,success){
    var script=document.createElement('script');
    script.src=url;
    var head=document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0],
        done=false;
    script.onload=script.onreadystatechange = function(){
      if ( !done && (!this.readyState || this.readyState == 'loaded' || this.readyState == 'complete') ) {
        done=true;
        success();
        script.onload = script.onreadystatechange = null;
        head.removeChild(script);
      }
    };
    head.appendChild(script);
  }
    getScript('http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.2/jquery.min.js',function(){
        // YOUR CODE GOES HERE AND IS EXECUTED AFTER JQUERY LOADS
    });
})();
```

From this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5853358/1766140

Comment: looks great. gonna try it out +1

Comment: I used @tylermwashburn answer from the link you gave. It was shorter and better IMHO. Thanks for the link very useful!

Comment: Agree, that one is cleaner.