# jQuery mobile and render blocking javascript

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

Now I am pulling out my hair, because I do not know, how to serve google as they want.

I run the Pagespeed Insights on our site, and there are critical problems, like please remove the render blocking script above the fold. The suggestion is to try to load the scripts in asynch or deferred mode.

I tried it, and of course, our whole site is crashed. Why is it?

This is, because jQuery Mobile depends on jQuery, so it can not be loaded asynch or deferred.

Also, there are lot of scripts depends on jQuery, so I should be sure, the first thing what is loaded the jQuery.

Of course, I tried to find solutions for this, and I've [found one here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5852767/possible-to-defer-loading-of-jquery) on SO, but that does not works, the site is fall to pieces.

The site loads very fast, there are a lot of unformatted and bad aligned elements, and when script loaded, the site will ok, but this is very bad UX.

Can somebody tell me, what is the solution for this?