# Switching to JS Defer converts jquery ajax to reload whole page

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance, jquery-deferred

To improve performance of site I updated my javascript references to use defer, such as:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8=" crossorigin="anonymous" defer></script>
<script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.16.0/jquery.validate.min.js" defer></script>
<script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validation.unobtrusive/3.2.6/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js" defer></script>
<script src="js/plugins.js" defer></script>
<script src="js/main.js" defer></script>
```

This did improve page load performance. Unfortunately a side-effect is that jquery function that handled the form post no longer was done using AJAX, it tried to reload the whole page which resulted in just the returned content appearing on a freshed page, opposed to just updating a DIV.

Code:

```
<script>
    $(function () {
        $('form').submit(function () {
            if ($(this).valid()) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: this.action,
                    type: this.method,
                    data: $(this).serialize(),
                    success: function (result) {
                        $('#result').html(result);
                        document.getElementById('contactForm').style.display = "none";
                    }
                });
            }
            return false;
        });
    });
</script>
```

How do I update this jquery code to work correctly when the scripts are deferred?

Comment: Don't defer jQuery. Everything relies on that being loaded first. While [there are ways to get around this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5852767/possible-to-defer-loading-of-jquery) they're, frankly, clunky and overcomplicated for most situations.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan you can in fact defer jQuery. You just have to make sure dependencies are deferred as well.

Comment: How do make the function defer?

Comment: @mac9416 I'd be interested to hear your thoughts on how that could possibly work. If everything is deferred, you have no control over loading order; that's its entire point.

Comment: @Josh you already are; with the `defer` attribute on the `<script>` elements

Comment: Acutally you can use async and have control over the loading order but if I post a link here they will just bash and down vote me.

Comment: @Josh unlike the `async` attribute, `defer` [preserves order](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/speed/script-loading/).

Comment: @ibowankenobi no we won't. Comments are the correct place for links.

Comment: @mac9416 not in a reliable, cross browser way it doesn't. IE (as with most things) messes it up.

Comment: There is a small library I wrote for async called taskq (http://taskq.ibrahimtanyalcin.com) to use it in your case, https://medium.com/@ibowankenobi/get-that-google-psi-score-higher-28a7c992966e . You might not want to use this, in that case why can't you go for requestAnimationFrame loop until $('form') is defined?

Comment: @ibowankenobi `async` executes immediately after the script is downloaded, ignoring order. `defer` executes in order immediately before `DOMContentLoaded`.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan source? Which version(s) of IE misbehave?

Comment: Yes yes but I used a technique to trap function calls within async and execute them in order. This way the scripts are no longer render blocking because they are trapped within requestAnimationFrame + Promise (if supported, degrades to double rAF in ie9)

Comment: @mac9416 < IE10. Source: https://caniuse.com/#search=defer (see 'Known issues' tab). Also from your own link `IE < 10 says: I might execute 2.js halfway through the execution of 1.js. Isn’t that fun??`

Comment: Removing defer from jquery fixed the issue. Lighthouse performance audit didn't notice a Performance impact.

Comment: @Josh glad you got it working.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan, thx for help. If you want to post it as an answer I credit you.

Comment: Which link whose link?

Comment: @Josh no problem, added it for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest not using `defer` on the jQuery.js reference. jQuery plugins rely on the main jQuery library being loaded first.

[While there are ways to get around this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5852767/possible-to-defer-loading-of-jquery) they're, frankly, clunky and overcomplicated for most situations.

Answer (score 1):

In your case jQuery can be deferred easily, if you're okay with breaking compatibility for some (very small number of) browsers. There are several options:

**1) Control execution order with an event handler**

Use a non-jQuery method to attach to `DOMContentLoaded`. i.e. instead of

```
$(function() {
    // handle form work
});
```

You would use

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
    // handle form work
});
```

The second snippet accomplishes the same thing as `$(function() {})` but does so without requiring jQuery to be loaded while the page is being parsed. So when the listener executes, jQuery will be available.

Attaching to `DOMContentLoaded` is supported by [98% of browsers](http://document.addEventListener(%22DOMContentLoaded%22,%20function(event)%20%7B). (Though you're still using `defer`, which limits you to [95% support](https://caniuse.com/#search=defer), max.)

There are also [polyfills](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/799981/document-ready-equivalent-without-jquery) for older browsers.

**2) Control execution order by moving some code out of the page**

You could move your `$('form')` event handler into an external script, deferred to load after jQuery. As Rory pointed out, `defer` has some [compatibility issues](https://caniuse.com/#search=defer). But at 95% support, it's still a pretty good option.

**3) Control execution order by bundling**

As Rory pointed out, you could also bundle (and minify, for better performance) and defer all your JS. That would ensure execution order (the browser would execute the single JS file from top to bottom). Browsers that don't support `defer` may not receive *all* the performance benefits, but at least the JS could not be broken by mis-ordering separate scripts.

Cross-origin, blocking, external scripts can be a **huge** [performance drain](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/performance/optimizing-content-efficiency/loading-third-party-javascript/). You'll have to weigh browser compatibility vs. performance. But if your target audience has mostly modern browsers, I would strongly suggest trying to defer jQuery.

Comment: Good answer. I'd also suggest that a third option would be to bundle & minify your JS files on the server and include a single reference to them which can then be deferred without concern over execution order.